# MySQL trying to get hourly summary and count on row data

Tags: mysql

MyTable is:

```
tday   char(3)
dow    int(1)
tdate  date
ttime  time
T0     decimal(5,2)
T1     decimal(5,2)
T2     decimal(5,2)
T3     decimal(5,2)
Total  decimal(8,2)
```

Given the above structure and following data:

```
DoW   IM     CDate       CTime     G0    G1   G2   G3

 Thu    4   2010-12-02   05:29:15    1    3    0    11
 Thu    4   2010-12-02   05:34:22    0    4    1    0
 Thu    4   2010-12-02   05:39:28    6    0    7    0
 Thu    4   2010-12-02   05:44:35    8    7    3    9
 Thu    4   2010-12-02   05:49:41    0    7    0    8
 Thu    4   2010-12-02   05:54:48    1    7    0    1
 Thu    4   2010-12-02   05:59:54    3    0    5    3
 Thu    4   2010-12-02   06:05:01    0    9    1    0
 Thu    4   2010-12-02   06:10:07    2    9   10    0
 Thu    4   2010-12-02   06:15:13    0    0   16    0
 Thu    4   2010-12-02   06:20:20    2    0    8    0
 Thu    4   2010-12-02   06:25:26    1    0    0    0
 Thu    4   2010-12-02   06:30:33    1    5   19   21
 Thu    4   2010-12-02   06:35:39    3    0    6    0
 Thu    4   2010-12-02   06:40:46    3    4    7    2
 Thu    4   2010-12-02   06:45:52    3    3    0   20
 Thu    4   2010-12-02   06:50:58    5    0    7   10
 Thu    4   2010-12-02   06:56:05    0    7    7    0
 Thu    4   2010-12-02   07:01:11    7    0   10    3
 Thu    4   2010-12-02   07:06:18    0    0    0    1
 Thu    4   2010-12-02   07:11:24    0    0    0    0
 Thu    4   2010-12-02   07:16:31    9    3    1    0
 Thu    4   2010-12-02   07:21:37    0    0    3   10
 Thu    4   2010-12-02   07:26:44    0    1    3    0
```

What I am trying to get is the sum of columns G0..G3  by the Hour per Day.

I have tried "Select CTime, sum(G0), sum(G1), sum(G2), sum(G3) from MyTable group by CTime order by CDate;" and various like statements without getting any success. The results I am trying to get is as follows:

```
DoW    IM   CDate        CTime      G0   G1   G2   G3

Thu    4    2010-12-02   05:00:00   19   28   16   32
Thu    4    2010-12-02   06:00:00   20   51   86   65
Thu    4    2010-12-02   07:00:00   16    4   17   14
```

Could you kindly assist.  I have spent considerable time looking at already submitted solutions and other answers on the web but nothing comes close to what I think I need in the particular SQL statement required.

Thanks. Grahame

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for something like

```
SELECT DoW, IM, CDate, HOUR(CTime) AS recorded_hour, SUM(G0) AS sum_0, 
    SUM(G1) AS sum)1, SUM(G2) AS sum_2, SUM(G3) AS sum_3
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY recorded_hour
```

If you want to have the hour for different dates to be distinct, then you just have to add the date column to the group by clause

Comment: You need to include the date in the grouping, as it is won't work.

Comment: That's exactly what I said in my answer... did you read it before downvoting?

Comment: Thank you - Thank you.  You have certainly shown me how to do it correctly. I have several other questions but I will spend some more time working on the issues before I post.

Comment: I also need to get a summary and totals by Day of the week, so a Monday-to-Friday sum of the G1..G3 columns.  I have tried several nonsensical statements which of course didn't work. I don't know if this is possible using just SQL, as I appear to have reached its limits (maybe).  Any comments appreciated.

Comment: That's quite doable.  Just take the query I posted and change the `GROUP BY` to `GROUP BY WEEK(CDate)`.  You'll probably need to remove the DoW, IM, and CTime columns from the select, since they'll just return random rows.

Comment: Sam - I certainly do appreciate your assistance and expertise help.  Could you point out a book or URL that covers such in-depth commands as all the material I have around me doesn't go into generating such reports in any such detail(s).  There are a lot more reports I need to do, and I would like to learn but without asking too much from volunteers such as yourself. Thanks Grahame.

Comment: For a reference to date functions - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html  and for grouping functions - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html and there's an overview of grouping at http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Answer (score 1):

What type of CTime and CDate is?
Could your past here normal table structure in pre&code

Try to run this:
`Select CDate, HOUR(CTime), sum(G0), sum(G1), sum(G2), sum(G3) from MyTable group by CDate, HOUR(CTime) order by CDate, CTime`

[HOUR function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour)

Comment: Last question hopefully.  Using the same SQL  statement as above, is it possible to get totals at the bottom of each col for col G0...G3 ?

Comment: What do your mean by 'total'?